# Enfocus swap img src to $(this).attr('src')

Tags: clojurescript

When mousing into a `.thumb` element I'd like to change `#full-image`'s `src` to the `.thumb` element's `src`. What I have that is not working:

```
(defaction change-src [selector src]
  [selector] (ef/set-attr :src src))

(defaction thumb-hover []
  [".thumb"] (events/listen :mouseenter
                     #(change-src "#full-image"
                                  ; Looks like the following needs to be replaced
                                  ; with some $(this).attr('src') equivalent.
                                  (ef/from % (ef/get-attr :src)))))
```

Can anyone point me to where I can use `this`? `Enfocus` is built on `domina` which is built on `closure` libs which is built on plain `js`. I don't know which layer I should be looking for `this` or if that is even the idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with `.-currentTarget`. See http://ckirkendall.github.io/enfocus-site/#doc-events and http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_events_Event.html.

```
(defaction change-src [selector src]
  [selector] (ef/set-attr :src src))

(defaction thumb-hover []
  [".thumb"] (events/listen :mouseenter
                     #(change-src "#full-image"
                                  (ef/from (.-currentTarget %)
                                           (ef/get-attr :src)))))
```